# WebClient cant load twitter page

Tags: javascript, java, webclient, htmlunit

Here is my code. I try to load twitter signup page with WebClient in Java.

```
public LoadTwitter() {
    client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    //client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000);
}

public void loadPage() throws IOException {
    HtmlPage page = client.getPage("http://twitter.com/signup");
}
```

But I have many javascript errors. If I turn off javascript. I get mobile version insteas of web. How to solve this problem?

```
янв 24, 2016 6:50:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
янв 24, 2016 6:50:27 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
янв 24, 2016 6:50:28 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
янв 24, 2016 6:50:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet isValidSelector
WARNING: Unhandled CSS condition type '7'. Accepting it silently.
янв 24, 2016 6:50:29 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector: *:x).] sourceName=[https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/en/init.c624198d27d7d00677cf16d484b32903b375bbc6.js] line=[108] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
янв 24, 2016 6:50:32 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[8] column=[0] lineSource=[null] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/en/bundle/signup.5fb6bc11a86475b13235f34876f4d57d28669252.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot call method "call" of undefined (https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/en/bundle/signup.5fb6bc11a86475b13235f34876f4d57d28669252.js#8)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "call" of undefined (https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/en/bundle/signup.5fb6bc11a86475b13235f34876f4d57d28669252.js#8)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:865)
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==
  function (b) {
      b = a.event || b;
      if (b.type == "load" || w(["loaded", "complete"], this.readyState) > -1) {
          this.onreadystatechange = null;
          c.loaded();
      }
  }
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should remove the logs by HtmlUnit:

```
LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
```

Comment: This code will turn off all the javascript warnings caused by htmlunit. These warnings are due to htmlunit library, not to your code, you should get the right content for your page.